# File's line numbering with sed

Tags: regex, bash, shell, sed, awk

I would like to know if sed is capable of doing some line counting work while numbering specific lines, suppose I have the file

```
  Some question 
         some answer
         another answer
  Another question
         another answer
         other answer
```

I want a command that transforms that into: **Desired Output**

```
  1_ Some question 
         a_ some answer
         b_ another answer
  2_ Another question
         a_ another answer
         b_ other answer
```

Is that possible with **sed**? If not, how can that be done without bash scripting a solution?

Comment: Can you be clearer about what your definition of "bash scripting" is and isn't?

Comment: a program made in bash that uses control structures like while, for, etc

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? What do you _need_ this for? I smell the [XY-problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) here

Comment: I'm needing this to properly format some hand-typed exam questions I copied today while learning about this topic in the process

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perl has a handy feature that `++` works on characters:

```
perl -lpe '
    /^\S/ and do {$inner_counter="a"; s/^/ ++${outer_counter} . "_ "/e}; 
    /^\s/ and s/^\s+/$& . ${inner_counter}++ . "_ "/e
' file
```

```
1_ Some question

     a_ some answer

     b_ another answer

2_ Another question

     a_ another answer

     b_ other answer
```

Answer (score 4):

It's better to try with [awk](/questions/tagged/awk). I assume that you want to number lines that don't begin with any withespace character:

```
awk '$0 !~ /^[[:blank:]]/ { print ++i "_", $0; next } { print }' infile
```

It yields:

```
1_ Some question
         some answer
         another answer
2_ Another question
         another answer
         other answer
```

Comment: Would u mind saying why would it be better trying with awk rathen than sed?

Comment: @NicoRodsevich: It's because `sed` can't use variables. Where do you keep the next number that you have to print? Difficult.